# How does MongoDB handle projection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I will have hundreds of fields in a document. If I only need one or two fields in a given document - does MongoDB transfer the whole document across the wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection is handled server-side, so only the fields that are included in the query's projection will be transferred over the wire.

In the C# driver, this is accomplished via the [`SetFields`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/99952427-4632-237f-fd90-8bfdc8a9e7ea.htm) method on `MongoCursor`.